# Variable value not replaced in double quoted string in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have read several threads here on SO but none of them seems to address my problem.  I have even tried some of the code samples but they don't work for me.

I have spent several days trying to figure this out but so far I've failed.  I don't think this a variable scope problem, but I could be wrong.  Since the actual script is too long to post I will show only my logic and I hope this is enough.

Main script logic:

```
<?php
require_once General functions
require_once Validator class
require_once DB table setup

function ForValidationRule()
{
}

if($_POST)
{
 validation rules
 if(validations pass)
 {
  variables set
  foreach(loop thru selected tables to create)
  {
    foreach(loop thru table array to build query)
    {
     $sql .= $data . PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
 }
}
?>
```

This is the table array used during my tests:

```
$tbl_names = array
(
 "`id_no` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,",
 "`type_id` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,",
 "`abbrev` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,",
 "`description` VARCHAR(75) NULL DEFAULT NULL,",
 "PRIMARY KEY (`id_no` ASC),",
 "UNIQUE INDEX `type_id-abbrev` (`type_id` ASC, `abbrev` ASC))",
 "ENGINE = {$engine}",
 "CHARACTER SET {$charset} COLLATE {$dbcoll}",
 "AUTO_INCREMENT = 2",
 "COMMENT = '{$company} {$tbl_name['names']['full']}';"
);
```

The 3 variables I'm having trouble with are: $engine, $dbcoll and $charset.  When I echo the variables before building the query they are correct.  When I echo the variable after building the query they are correct.  But this is the result of building the query:

```
CREATE TABLE `tester`.`name_pre-suf`(
`id_no` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type_id` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
`abbrev` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(75) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_no` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `type_id-abbrev` (`type_id` ASC, `abbrev` ASC))
ENGINE = 
CHARACTER SET  COLLATE 
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
COMMENT = 'CEF, Inc. Name Prefixes/Suffixes File';
```

As can be seen all 3 variables are blank in the query.  Using 1 variable, $engine, I have tried several methods but none work.

```
"ENGINE = {${$engine}}"
"ENGINE = " . $engine
'ENGINE = ' . $engine
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?  The code does work correctly if I hard code the values instead of using variables.

**EDIT 1:**
I made a mistake in my original logic sample.  The variables are set before entering any foreach loop.  I have corrected the logic sample.  This is how I set those variables:

```
$dbhost = $_POST['dbhost'];
$dbuser = $_POST['dbuser'];
$dbpass = $_POST['dbpass'];
$dbname = $_POST['dbname'];
$dbcoll = str_ToLower($_POST['dbcoll']);
$dbcoll_ary = explode("_", $dbcoll);
$charset = trim($dbcoll_ary['0']);
$engine = 'innodb';
if($charset == 'utf8mb4')
{
 $engine = 'innodb ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC';
}
```

And this is where I echo before building the query and after.

```
echo($engine . PHP_EOL);
echo($dbcoll . PHP_EOL);
echo($charset . PHP_EOL);
   $sql = "CREATE TABLE `$dbname`.`{$tbl_name[$key]['db']}`(" . PHP_EOL;
   foreach(${'tbl_' . $key} as $data)
   {
    $sql .= $data . PHP_EOL;
   } // Closing brace for foreach(${'tbl_' . $key} as $data)
echo($engine . PHP_EOL);
echo($dbcoll . PHP_EOL);
echo($charset . PHP_EOL);
echo($sql . PHP_EOL);
exit();
```

The echoed values are correct, they are the values the user selected.

**EDIT 2:**
Table names and table setup are defined in the table file that gets included using the require_once command.  Here is the table names array and the 1st table array that I'm using for my tests.

```
$company = defined('COMPANY_NAME_SHORT') ? COMPANY_NAME_SHORT : '';

$tbl_name = array
(
 'names' => array('db' => 'name_pre-suf', 'full' => 'Name Prefixes/Suffixes File'),
 'tmzn' => array('db' => 'timezones', 'full' => 'Timezones File'),
 'curr' => array('db' => 'currency', 'full' => 'Currency File'),
 'langtyp' => array('db' => 'language_types', 'full' => 'Language Types File'),
 'lang' => array('db' => 'language', 'full' => 'Language File'),
 'cntyp' => array('db' => 'country_types', 'full' => 'Country Types/Sub-Types File'),
 'cntry' => array('db' => 'countries', 'full' => 'Countries'),
 'terri' => array('db' => 'territories', 'full' => 'Territories'),
 'trans' => array('db' => 'translations', 'full' => 'Translations'),
 'langu' => array('db' => 'languages', 'full' => 'Languages'),
 'curry' => array('db' => 'currencies', 'full' => 'Currencies'),
 'dialc' => array('db' => 'dial_codes', 'full' => 'Dialing Codes'),
 'topld' => array('db' => 'tl_domains', 'full' => 'Top Level Domains'),
 'users' => array('db' => 'users', 'full' => 'Users'),
 'usact' => array('db' => 'users_activity', 'full' => 'Users Activity'),
);

$tbl_names = array
(
 "`id_no` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,",
 "`type_id` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,",
 "`abbrev` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,",
 "`description` VARCHAR(75) NULL DEFAULT NULL,",
 "PRIMARY KEY (`id_no` ASC),",
 "UNIQUE INDEX `type_id-abbrev` (`type_id` ASC, `abbrev` ASC))",
 "ENGINE = {$engine}",
 "CHARACTER SET {$charset} COLLATE {$dbcoll}",
 "AUTO_INCREMENT = 2",
 "COMMENT = '{$company} {$tbl_name['names']['full']}';"
);
```

The main script is almost 600 lines (which includes all php, html and javascript) while the table setup (1 table name array and all the separate table arrays) file is about 300 lines.  Can I attach files in SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this works perfectly:

```
<?php

$engine = "InnoDB";
$dbcoll = "utf8_general_ci";
$charset = "utf8";

$tbl_names = array
(
 "`id_no` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,",
 "`type_id` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,",
 "`abbrev` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,",
 "`description` VARCHAR(75) NULL DEFAULT NULL,",
 "PRIMARY KEY (`id_no` ASC),",
 "UNIQUE INDEX `type_id-abbrev` (`type_id` ASC, `abbrev` ASC))",
 "ENGINE = {$engine}",
 "CHARACTER SET {$charset} COLLATE {$dbcoll}",
 "AUTO_INCREMENT = 2",
 "COMMENT = '{$company} {$tbl_name['names']['full']}';"
);

foreach($tbl_names as $value){
 echo $value .PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

I will assume that all your variables are empty. Check if `$charset`, `$engine`, `$dbcoll` have values asigned to them.

**Edit:** (More info provided by the OP)

The problem is that when you declare your array, the variables **are not set**.

If you have the variables after you declare the array, your code won't work as you expected.

```
<?php
//This won't work.
$tbl_names = array(/*..*/);

$engine = "InnoDB";
$dbcoll = "utf8_general_ci";
$charset = "utf8";

?>
```

So, declare the variables before you declare the array.

I would recommend something like this.

```
<?php
    //Validate the $_POST for valid values...
    $engine = !empty($_POST["engine"]) $_POST["engine"] ? "InnoDB"; 
    $dbcoll = !empty($_POST["dbcoll"]) $_POST["dbcoll"] ? "utf8_general_ci";
    $charset = !empty($_POST["charset"]) $_POST["charset"] ? "utf8";

    $tbl_names = array(/*..*/);
    //Now $tbl_names will have the correct values. 
    //The default ones, or the user submitted ones

?>
```

Using your code snippet:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = $_POST['dbhost'];
    $dbuser = $_POST['dbuser'];
    $dbpass = $_POST['dbpass'];
    $dbname = $_POST['dbname'];
    $dbcoll = str_ToLower($_POST['dbcoll']);
    $dbcoll_ary = explode("_", $dbcoll);
    $charset = trim($dbcoll_ary['0']);
    $engine = 'innodb';

    if($charset == 'utf8mb4'){
        $engine = 'innodb ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC';
    }

    //if you set your $tbl_name array here, it will work.
    include("table_names.php");

   $sql = "CREATE TABLE `$dbname`.`{$tbl_name[$key]['db']}`(" . PHP_EOL;
   foreach(${'tbl_' . $key} as $data){
        $sql .= $data . PHP_EOL;
   } // Closing brace for foreach(${'tbl_' . $key} as $data)

?>
```

The problem is that you're including your array, **before** your variables even exists, that's why you need to include the file after the variables are set.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  If I declare and set the variables inside the table array file then those values are used.  But, they are not changed by the user selection in the query loop.  The user selects what COLLATE value to use before the script runs.  The 3 variables are set because I echo them before the query loop and after.  They are set.

Comment: I have declared and set the variables at the very top of the main script, before any of the require_once.  I have also declared and set the variables at the very top of the table array file.  Both cases result in the variable values used in the loop are the declared values not the actual uers selected value.  In other words, if the user selects 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' 'utf8_general_ci' is still used.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I was trying to explain, if you have default values, you have to redeclare the array after the user submitted values.  check my new update.

Comment: Yes, I do set the same variables to the users selected value after the $_POST validation and before the query loop is run.  In other words, I do set the variable values to be the users selected value and I can echo them out before and after the query loop is run.  The variables do contain the users selected value but the declared values are still used.  Am I not seeing something you are trying to say?  I don't declare the table array at all because they are in the table array file that get loaded using the require_once command.

Comment: Can you post where you output the table, and where is $tbl_names set, or post the full code. It's hard to explain If I don't have the full code.

Comment: Please see Edit 1 in my question.

Comment: @CharlesEF I still don't see where in your code $tbl_names (your array) is set.

Comment: Please see Edit 2 in my question.

Comment: As I have said, I have declared and set default values for all 3 variables at the very top of the main script file, before any require_once commands.  That results in the default values being used in the building of the table query not the user selected values.  I can't just move the require_once command where you want because it is needed to build the table selection checkboxes in the HTML page.  My website is down right now because I forgot to renew my domain.  Give me a few days and I will post the actual files and send you a link.  Is this okay?

Comment: My code snippet is working, since I don't have more data available, I don't know where the problem is, I can wait, just remember to post a comment ;)

Comment: Never mind, I got it working.  I had to split the DB table setup file into 2 pages.  1 page has the table names array that gets included at the very top of the main script.  The other page is the table definition arrays that gets included at the place where you suggested, after the variables are defined  It appears variable value substitution only happens once, at the time the page is included.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was trying to say, that you needed to include the file after the variables were defined, I'm glad you could make it work!